A Korean horror movie in 2004 about a ghost trying to protect her unborn baby from medical experiments
I watched this particular movie a long time ago. 
It's about a couple who falls in a beautiful romance. Then the guy who is a doctor leaves town and works far away. 
They live apart from each other for months until one day the girl finally finds out the boy she loved at a hospital. The boy rejects the girl and leaves her waiting for him for hours in the rain. Then the girl dies and he realizes that she was pregnant with their baby. Then in the morgue, the doctor hangs himself in remorse.
Years later, the hospital then uses that girl's unborn baby for some experiments without permission and she rises up from the dead to haunt them. There are these two medical students who get unexpectedly involved in this and the mother ghost happens to tell them her story.
It was truly a good movie. I have been searching all over but there's no way I can find the name of this movie. It was around 2007 or 2008 that I saw the movie but I'm not quite sure the year the movie was released. 2005 or 2006? Please help me, much appreciated!

Hi, how are you sure it was Korean movie? I looked through every horror movie produced in S.Korea on 2004 ~ 2008 without much luck.
